# python - how to specify return type hint for a method that returns a new object

Tags: python, type-hinting, class-design

I'll first introduce my situation and then ask the question.

So I already have the following code written and can not be changed:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, number: int, letter: str):
        self.number = number
        self.letter = letter

    @classmethod
    def create_new(cls, number: int, letter: str):
        return cls(number, letter)
```

As you can see, the method `create_new` can create new objects from given attributes. Obviously, in real life, the class itself isn't called "A" and the methods are far more complicated. For the sake of the example, I distilled the staff that matters.

Now, I want to add the following method to the class:

```
    def create_new_with_different_number(self, number: int):
        return self.create_new(number, self.letter)
```

in order to allow the user to create new, almost-identical object, with only one attribute changed (in this example - the same object only with different number).

Is there a way for me to precisely indicate the return type of `create_new_with_different_number`? Something like:

```
    def create_new_with_different_number(self, number: int) -> A:
        return self.create_new(number, self.letter)
```

won't work, since "A" is not defined yet when the method is being defined.

P.S:
I know the situation might sound complex and seem like a bad design, but it is what it is and I need to only add my method, not change the existing ones.

Comment: This is the problem solved by [pep-563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) which hasn't been merged yet. If you use `from__future__ import annotations` you can use `A`

Comment: There is also a `Self` type proposed for Python 3.11 in [pep-673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) but I'm not sure if there's a way of using that yet.

Comment: Can’t you use `def create_new_with_different_number(self, number: int) -> "A":`?